# Select ALL instead of ANY in a Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

Currently we have the following sample DB structure with a Many-to-Many relationship between `lead` and `tag` tables.

```
CREATE TABLE lead ( id serial
        constraint lead_id_pk
            primary key, name VARCHAR(20), surname VARCHAR(20) );

CREATE TABLE tag ( id serial
        constraint tag_id_pk
            primary key, name VARCHAR(20), description Text );

create table leads_tags
(
    id         serial
        constraint lead_tags_id_pk
            primary key,
    lead_id    integer not null
        constraint leads_tags_leads_id_fk
            references lead
            on delete cascade,
    tag_id     integer not null
        constraint leads_tags_tags_id_fk
            references tag
            on delete cascade,
    constraint leads_tags_lead_id_tag_id_key
        unique (lead_id, tag_id)
);
```

Let's imagine that we would like to perform the following queries.

1. Give me all the leads that have **ANY** of the tags in a list.
2. Give me all the leads that have **ALL** of the tags in the list

For the first one (1) we can do:

```
Select distinct (id), *
FROM lead
where id in (
    Select lt.lead_id
    from leads_tags lt
    where tag_id in (324, 129)
    )
```

For the second one (2) where we want to search for Leads that have both tags. Which is the most performant option according to your opinion? Is this the best approach?

```
SELECT *
FROM lead
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT lt.lead_id
    FROM leads_tags lt
    GROUP BY lt.lead_id
    HAVING array_agg(tag_id) @> array [324,129]
)
```

Comment: **1)** `EXISTS(..)` **2)** `NOT EXISTS .. ( NOT EXISTS(..))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided `unique (lead_id, tag_id)` I would say

```
SELECT *
FROM lead
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT lt.lead_id
    FROM leads_tags lt
    GROUP BY lt.lead_id
    where tag_id in (324, 129)
    HAVING count(*) = 2
)
```

Comment: This will not work. We do not want to search if they have a tag twice. We want to ensure that there is always ALL the tags.

Comment: Your `leads_tags` table definition prohibits a lead from having the same tag twice. Just test the query.

Comment: They can't have the tag twice because you have a unique constraint.  This query is ensuring that you have both tags.

Comment: I'd also use a join or exists rather than in()

Comment: Thanks it works. @Serg will this be faster than `array_agg` ?

Comment: @glarkou,  I don't expect a big difference, but counting is slightly less work then constructing an array.